# Search for last occurence of an duplicated item in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find out how to obtain the last recurring S/N of a product for the respective "person".

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| S/N | Person A | Person B | Person C | Person D |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1a  | 1a       |          |          |          |
| 2a  |          | 2a       |          |          |
| 3a  |          |          |          | 3a       |
| 4a  |          |          | 4a       |          |
| 1a  |          |          | 1a       |          |  
| 1a  |          |          |          | 1a       |
| 3a  | 3a       |          |          |          |
| 2a  |          | 2a       |          |          |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

In this case, the S/N for "1a" occurs three times for three different persons. I would like to find out the final person assigned to "1a", which in this case, would be person D.

I've tried using the index function but i think I'm understanding the use of the equation wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "1a" (search term) is in `I1` then use:

```
=INDEX(B1:E1,,MATCH(I1,INDEX(B:E,MAX(INDEX(ROW(A2:A9)*(A2:A9=I1),)),),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternate formula to Dirk Reichel's

=AGGREGATE(14,4,($B$2:$E$9=G2)*COLUMN($B$2:$E$9),1)

It is a wee bit shorter, but wont work unless your version of excel supports the aggregate function.  Dirk's should work in earlier versions.

[image: Proof of concept]